# With Node/Express, how can I serve static files from React for a specific route only?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

In my `server.js` file for my Express application, I am importing a router with

```
const portfolio = require('./routes/portfolio')
```

and I am accessing it through

```
app.use('/portfolio', portfolio);
```

Inside this router, I have the following:

```
router.use('/loanamort', (req, res, next) => {
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'portfolio','loanamort','build'));
    next();
})
```

I am trying to access the `index.html` file in the React build folder. However it won't serve the files when I try to access the URL `"localhost:port/portfolio/loanamort"`. It does work when I do the same thing through the `server.js` file with:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'portfolio','loanamort','build')));
```

I don't understand why, and I would like to only serve and access the `index.html` only when users go through the `/portfolio/loanamort` URL path. How can I fix this?

For context, my project build is as follows:

```
application
    |- server.js
    |- routes
         |- portfolio.js
         |- portfolio
               |- loanamort
                      |- build
                          |- index.html
                          |- static
```

Comment: A general advice is to read the documentation of the thing you are interested in first. Had you done that, there would most likely be no question at all. Some documentations can be really tough to understand. Not the case with ExpressJS, it's quite straightforward and concise.

Answer (score 0):

`express.static()` returns a middleware ***function***. This function is then supposed to be passed into the middleware handler, which will in turn ***call that function*** when its route matches:

```
const staticMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'portfolio', 'loanamort', 'build'));
// staticMiddleware holds a reference to a **function**!
app.use(staticMiddleware);
```

So in order to get your code to work, you have to *call* that function in your route handler:

```
// Declare the middleware outside of ".use()", so that you don't re-instantiate
// it for every request.
const staticMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'portfolio', 'loanamort', 'build'));
router.use('/loanamort', (req, res, next) => {
    staticMiddleware(req, res, next);
})
```

`staticMiddleware` will call `next()` itself, so this code should work just fine. Read more about express middleware here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#using-middleware.

However, you can simply indicate the path for which the static server should be used:

```
app.use('/loanamort', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'portfolio', 'loanamort', 'build')));
```

Obvious when you see it, isn't it? Read more about this solution and `express.static()` here: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#serving-static-files-in-express.

Occasionally I will use the above, more complicated solution when I want to modify the middleware function before calling it.